# (Photoshop) How do I get rid of grid/pixels every time I draw with brush tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency, background

[image]

I searched and did everything like going to the preference and turning off the *transparency grid*, changing the *snap to*, unchecking the *extra*....and creating a new document setting the grid to none. I don't know what to do. Please help!

*I want to upload a screen recording, but I don't think I can here. So I am uploading the screenshots*

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a pattern in the brush itself.

Comment: Hi @Anjee I think I see the confusion. As the brush settings for the texture are set to low contrast and/or brightness, the texture would be less apparent in very dark/very light strokes... Have you tried choosing another texture or scaling it in the Brush dialog?

Comment: @Metis Sorry, I was wrong. It was the texture of the brush. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @johnp I did not realize that it was the brush. Just knew it after reading the answer on my post.. I am doing that now :) Thank you for your comment!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your specific brush settings, it appears that you have applied a repeating texture to your brush.

You have two options:

A) Adjust the Scale, Brightness and Contrast of the texture for a more subtle output

B) Select a more seamless texture pattern in the Brush-settings dialog

[image]

NB: Brush Tool Presets embed textures in their settings, which may account for any differences in behaviour between various brushes

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I never knew that it was the brush!! Thank you!!

Comment: Your welcome :) If the answer helped you, you can click to accept it. Ps. Welcome to GDSE.